# keep icon to the bottom right of a table cell after text input

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm having trouble keeping the icon in one place of a table cell (in this case, bottom right corner of the table cell). When I input some text in the cell, the icon's position shifts to weird locations and that is not what I want.

```
<style>
table, th, td {
font-size: 16px;
text-align:center;

}
i.fa-pencil {
position: fixed;
right: 1160px;
bottom:520px;
}
td{
height:100px;
}

</style>

<td ><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="description"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>+val['description']+</div></td>
```

before:

[image: before.png]

after:

[image: after.png]

Comment: Can you create demo of your problem so we can have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position your element `absolute` instead `fixed`.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row_data {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

i.fa-pencil {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

td {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eed659c9d4.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="description"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

If your requirement is different, please post it with example.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if this works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
.row_data{
    position:relative;
}
i.fa-pencil { 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0px; 
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Change right or bottom depend on the margin you want.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `fixed` position used `absolute` position to your icon see demo below

```css
table, th, td {
font-size: 16px;
text-align:center;

}

td{
height:100px;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    position: relative;
}

td .fa {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td ><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="description"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>hfjkdf fhdks fhdsk fdshjk</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```